# save escaping method reference in swift

Tags: swift, closures

I am a Java/Kotlin programmer and new to swift. I want to pass a method reference in a constructor to save it for later use. The method I want to pass looks like this:

```
func refresh(completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
    ...
}
```

What I want to do is instantiate an object and pass this method as a parameter like this:

```
    refreshControl = Refresher() {
        compl -> Void in
        self.refresh(completion: compl)
    }
```

The class I want to pass this function to looks like this:

```
class Refresher  {

   let refresh:  (@escaping (Error?) -> ()) -> Void

   init(refresh: (@escaping (Error?) -> ()) -> Void) {
       self.refresh = refresh
   }

   // call refresh somewhere later
}
```

This does not compile with error "Assigning non-escaping parameter 'refresh' to an @escaping closure. Not entirely sure what escaping does but I know I need it in the actual refresh function. I am not sure how to syntax this right. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But Xcode *tells* you what to do. It offers you a Fix-It:

```
init(refresh: @escaping (@escaping (Error?) -> ()) -> Void) {
```

Personally I would then get rid of the *other* `@escaping` stuff you've put in, as it is not needed. So:

```
class Refresher  {

    let refresh:  ((Error?) -> ()) -> Void

    init(refresh: @escaping ((Error?) -> ()) -> Void) {
        self.refresh = refresh
    }

}
```

And elsewhere:

```
func refresh(completion: (Error?) -> ()) {
   // ...
}
func f() {
    let refreshControl = Refresher() {
        compl -> Void in
        self.refresh(completion: compl)
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, is there something like a method reference in swift?

I mean can we reduce this somehow:
    let refreshControl = Refresher() {
        compl -> Void in
        self.refresh(completion: compl)
    }

in java we would just write new Refresher(this::refresh)

Comment: Well, sure, the bare name `refresh` is a reference to the function `refresh`, if that's what you mean, and it can be passed wherever a function of that same type is expected. However, that's not what you asked, and the very nature of your asking it now makes me think that maybe the type `((Error?) -> ()) -> Void` was never what you really intended.

Comment: I could refactor the instantiation to: `refreshControl = Refresher(refresh: refresh(completion:))` which is what I wanted, thanks